# How to script the startup of an app using multiple precursory values?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, webserver, ruby

I have a webapp I'd like to start with a script, rather than open 3 tabs and start the processes, then change a line to a config file, and then start the web server.

First, so I can test webhooks, I need to run `ngrok http https://localhost:3000`, which yields something just as so--

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                                                               (Ctrl+C to quit)
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Session Status                online                                                                                                                                                                    
Account                       myemail@gmail.com (Plan: Free)                                                                                                                                     
Version                       2.3.35                                                                                                                                                                    
Region                        United States (us)                                                                                                                                                        
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                                                                                     
Forwarding                    http://2f22e8990cbe.ngrok.io -> https://localhost:3000                                                                                                                    
Forwarding                    https://2f22e8990cbe.ngrok.io -> https://localhost:3000                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                                                                               
                              13973   1       0.00    0.07    0.00    0.00
```

I then change a config file to accommodate the new host (random for the free usage of `ngrok`)

```
# development.rb
config.hosts << '2f22e8990cbe.ngrok.io' # (tunnel address from above)
```

I then save the file and start the webserver.

```
$ rails server puma --bind 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=/home/oaty/.ssh/localhost.key&cert=/home/oaty/.ssh/localhost.crt'
```

I'd like to script this into one command. I can use a larger, shell environment variable for the ngrok host, tho I have to get that somehow from the same script, to begin with. I hope I'm not asking too much. I really love the Ubuntu forums. I'm too Autistic, I guess, for most other places. Viva Ubuntu!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to get the `2f22e8990cbe.ngrok.io` part from the output of `ngrok` where the `2f22e8990cbe` part is variable, then run `config.hosts` with that part as input stop token (which is what the `<<` means), and then run the `rails` command which does not depend on the previous commands. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. I need to grep the ngrok host and replace the existing one in the config file.tThank  yoy. Rails command is a standalone command here, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
newhost=$(ngrok http https://localhost:3000 | \
    grep -E '^Forwarding\s+https://' | \
    grep -E  -o '[0-9a-f]{12}\.ngrok\.io`)
  
if [[ -n "$newhost" ]] ; then
    echo "$newhost" >>config.hosts
    rails server ...(the rest)
else
    echo "Failure in ngrok" >&2
fi
```

Read `man grep bash`.

Comment: With your encouragement, I found an answer. I don't know why the '&' ampersand still won't suppress both ngrok and then the log. It's okay as it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by drilling down more accurately. I've adapted the code a little. The `curl` with `jq` command is the real pearl. Thank you.
(Note: localhost:4040 is `ngrok`'s web ui page.)

### boot_ssl.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sh -c 'ngrok http https://localhost:3000 &'
sleep 2
curl --silent http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels | jq '.tunnels[0].public_url' > .ngrok_ssl_host
rails s puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=/home/jess/.ssh/localhost.key&cert=/home/jess/.ssh/localhost.crt'
```

### and then in the config/development.rb file... :)

```
  NGROK_SSL_HOST = File.open('.ngrok_ssl_host').read.match(/[0-9a-z]{12}\.ngrok\.io/)[0]
  
  config.hosts << NGROK_SSL_HOST
```